# SQL - Help on Converting SQL Syntax to MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I need help on this, I need to convert a SQL syntax to MS Access syntax and I don't know how.

```
INSERT INTO SampleData2
    SELECT 
        Object_Account, Descriptions, GL_Date, Document_Type, 
        Document_Number, Company, Subledger, Subledger_Type, ' ', 
        SUM(Actual_Amount * -1) AS TotalAmount, 
        (JE_Explantion) AS Explanation 
    FROM 
        SampleData
    WHERE 
        CAST(Object_Account AS VARCHAR(20)) + Subledger + JE_Explantion 
           IN (SELECT CAST(Object_Account AS VARCHAR(20)) + Subledger +  JE_Explantion 
               FROM SampleData 
               GROUP BY Object_Account, Subledger, JE_Explantion 
               HAVING COUNT(Object_Account) > 1)
    GROUP BY 
        Object_Account, Descriptions, GL_Date, Document_Type, 
        Document_Number, Company, Subledger, Subledger_Type, Remarks, 
        JE_Explantion
```

Comment: I don't see any vendor-specific parts in your code...

Comment: Please be more specific about what you tried and what is not working.

Comment: Is the problem that you are using CAST()?

Answer (score 1):

MS Access uses & for string concatenation and doesn't support `cast()`.  You might try:

```
INSERT INTO SampleData2
    SELECT Object_Account, Descriptions, GL_Date, Document_Type, Document_Number,
           Company, Subledger, Subledger_Type, ' ', Sum(Actual_Amount * -1) AS TotalAmount, (JE_Explantion) As Explanation
    FROM SampleData as sd
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM SampleData as sd2
                  WHERE sd2.Object_Account = sd.Object_Account AND
                        sd2.Subledger = sd.Subledger AND
                        sd2.JE_Explantion = sd.JE_Explantion
                  GROUP BY Object_Account, Subledger, JE_Explantion 
                  HAVING COUNT(Object_Account) > 1
                 )
    GROUP BY Object_Account, Descriptions, GL_Date, Document_Type, Document_Number, 
Company, Subledger, Subledger_Type, Remarks, JE_Explantion;
```